# log4j + log4mongo - Configure multiple appenders with different levels

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, log4j

I am trying to configure log4j to log everything into my log file appender and all the errors to **mongoDbAppender**.

If I add the **mongoDbAppender** to the root logger, then it logs everything to it as well as to the log file.

But if I create a separate logger and assign it a **error** level or any other level, it does not log anything to the mongoDbAppender.

Following is how my log4j.xml looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{application} %X{ua} %5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/var/www/log/logfile.log"/>
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logfile.%d.log.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{application} %X{ua} %5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="mongo" class="org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender">
    <param name="hostname" value="localhost"/>
    <param name="port" value="27017"/>
    <param name="databaseName" value="test"/>
    <param name="collectionName" value="errorBundle"/>
</appender>

<logger name="errorlogger">
   <level value="error"/>
   <appender-ref ref="mongo" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

I also tried to add a filter to the mongodb appender and added it to the root logger stack, then also it did not log anything to mongodb.

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="error"/>
        <param name="LevelMax" value="error"/>
</filter>
```

Please help me, what I am doing wrong. How can I log only the errors in mongodb appender.

Thanking You.

Comment: try value="ERROR" with caps.

Comment: Don't read my last comment, i dind't read well enough, so Look http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/mongodb.html, you haven't set the param password neither username, and for the error filters use this example from the docs http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/filters.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply @iFrey, but I do not need the username and password parameters if authentication is not enabled on my mongodb. The filter example you referred to is for PHP and I am implementing in Java, anyways I have implemented it in the same way. Can you please point out if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: I will put this as an answer because code looks bad on comments

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what have you tried, so try to configure the error level of your appender this way:

```
<appender name="mongo" class="org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender">
    <param name="hostname" value="localhost"/>
    <param name="port" value="27017"/>
    <param name="databaseName" value="test"/>
    <param name="collectionName" value="errorBundle"/>
     <filter class="LoggerFilterLevelRange">
        <param name="levelMin" value="error" />
        <param name="levelMax" value="error" />
    </filter>
</appender>
```